# What is the NetBeans "Return of Collection Field" optional warning?

Tags: java, netbeans, collections, warnings

I'm enabling as many optional warnings in NetBeans as I can, in an attempt to become a better coder. One of them is "Return of Collection Field". Its entire description is "Warns about return of collection fields". [The Wiki wasn't any more helpful.](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Java_Hints)

[image: Screenshot of the option to enable this error.]

What does this mean? How can it be harmful to return a collection field?

Comment: Probably referring to the mutability of the `Collection`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Could you elaborate?

Comment: You're leaking the state of object to which the field belongs. If you modify the collection after your retrieve it, you're potentially ruining the state of that object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many collection classes in Java such as `ArrayList`, `HashSet` and `TreeMap` are mutable. This means that you can change them (by adding items or clearing them, for example). This means that you have to be careful when writing an immutable class that your getter for a collection field returns a *copy*.

For example, you should do this:

```
public final class Example {

    private final List<Integer> list;

    public Example(List<? extends Integer> list) {
        this.list = new ArrayList<Integer>(list);
    }

    public List<Integer> getList() {
        return new ArrayList<Integer>(list);
    }
}
```

If `getList()` had simply said `return list;` the caller would have had a reference to the private field `list` itself, so any changes made to the returned object would mutate the instance of `Example`.

That warning presumably tells you when you write something like `return list;`. My advice would be to keep that optional warning on, as it's extremely easy to write `return list;` without thinking, and the results can be very confusing.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. This shouldn't be an issue, since I was simply using `return this;` in a collection subclass to make it possible to chain commands (like `collection.add(foo).add(bar).toArray()`). Related: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=251354

Comment: @Supuhstar I wish `ArrayList` worked like that. The return value of `true` when you `add` an item is completely useless.

Comment: returning a copy of a list isn't great either. you could think you're adding items into the object's collection, when you're actually adding them to a temporary object. really what you should do is write `addItem` and `removeItem` methods for that type (and whatever other kinds of specific functions you need exposed).

Answer (score 1):

@Sahuagin
To prevent that, you can use

```
public List<Integer> getList() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: Hi, welcome. While your answer is certainly correct, it does not address the original question of "why it is considered harmful to return a  collection".

Comment: I discovered this yesterday. You can also return an `Iterable` reference instead of `List`, and then clients will know they can't modify the collection. Otherwise it looks like a list but will just throw exceptions if you try to use it which is not good. `Iterable` and `unmodifiableList` work well together to solve this issue.